# Toggle between the visibility of 2 divs in reactjs

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a simple reactjs website hosted on GitHub Pages. It lists articles, something like feeds in reddit. I have an AddArticle requirement, wherein, upon clicking the 'Add Article' button on the bottom of the page, the Div containing this button must become hidden, and a new Div for adding the details of the article(containing 2 text-boxes and a button named 'Submit') must show up. Upon clicking the 'Submit' button, the earlier Div has to reappear with the new Div getting hidden.

The following is the code I currently use(that is incomplete). Please go through it and provide any insight into the problem. Thanks.

```js
class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onClickSubmitButton = this.onClickSubmitButton.bind(this);

    this.state = { 
      showing: false 
    };
  }

  onClickSubmitButton(){
    console.log('test-2');

    this.setState(
      { 
        showing: true 
      }
    );
  }

  render() {
    const { showing } = this.state;
    return (
      <div id="div_2">
      <br/>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Add the article title here" className="block_text"></input>
      <br/><br/>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Add the article text here" className="block_text"></input>
      <br/><br/>
      <button 
        type="button" 
        onClick={() => 
        this.onClickSubmitButton()}
      >
        Submit
      </button>
      { showing 
                    ? <div>This is visible</div>
                    : null
      }

    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default class AddArticle extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onClickAddButton = this.onClickAddButton.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      error: undefined,
      tempArticle: undefined,
      childVisible: false,
      parentVisible: true
    };
  }

  onClickAddButton(){
    console.log('test-1');

    this.setState(
      prevState => (
        { 
          childVisible: !prevState.childVisible,
          parentVisible: !prevState.parentVisible 
        }
      )
    );
    
  }

  // this is the render method
  render() {
    
    return (
        
          <div id="div_1">
            <br/><br/>
            <button 
              type="button" 
              onClick={() => 
              this.onClickAddButton()}
            >
              Add Article
            </button>
            {
            
            this.state.childVisible
            ? <Child />
            : null

            }
          </div>

    );

  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The problem would probably be easier to wrap your head around if you thought of your code more closely in relation to the problem. Right now you have variable names like `Child`, `childVisible`, `parentVisible`, `onClickAddButton`, etc. which don't describe the purpose of the program very well. Instead, use names like `NewArticleForm`, or `newArticleFormVisible`, and so on.

Comment: Additionally, here's a good article from the react docs which should help in approaching the problem a little better: https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution. You should had just send prop to the `<Child />` component

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-darkness-c1ft9)